# How to put hin.cube.lm in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I have used successfully OCR with english language. Now i want to support the hindi language. For this i have downloaded hindi traindedata from [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseractindic/downloads/detail?name=Hindi_training_data-0.1.tar.gz&can=1&q=hindi) and now it is showing the below error when i try to run the program

```
Lex iCityPediaUniversal/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/tessdata/hin.cube.lm
    cd "/Users/user1/Desktop/PROJECTS/LingoDiction Latest/iCityPediaUniversal"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    lex -o/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LingoDiction-fcotfygpaazbeqceuqwgorowixck/Build/Intermediates/LingoDiction.build/Debug-iphoneos/LingoDiction.build/DerivedSources/hin.cube.yy.m /Users/user1/Desktop/PROJECTS/LingoDiction\ Latest/iCityPediaUniversal/iCityPediaUniversal/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/tessdata/hin.cube.lm

/Users/user1/Desktop/PROJECTS/LingoDiction Latest/iCityPediaUniversal/iCityPediaUniversal/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/tessdata/hin.cube.lm:8: premature EOF
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex failed with exit code 1
```

what actually i want to ask is how i can use a .lm Extension file in xcode as this error is due to .lm extension file which i downloaded.

please help, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Check under `Build Phases` in XCode's project/target settings to make sure the *.lm file isn't in the sources list.

Specifically, look at the "Compile Sources" section. XCode likely took the liberty of adding the *.lm file to this list when you added the tessdata files.  Simply remove the *.lm file from the list and recompile!

Answer (score 1):

lex is a tool for writing parsers. The error is telling you that the file "hin.cube.lm" ended at line 8 and more data was expected by lex. Is it possible that the file was damaged when you downloaded it? Perhaps only part of the file got downloaded?

Comment: Yes,You are absolutely right that the file named "hin.cube.lm" is ends with "premature EOF" for which I downloaded the file again but still I am receiving the same error. while surfing a little i found that this is the old version of training data i.e of NOV,2009 so I downloaded the new version now but again it shows the same error.